# Worflow for scaffolding additional models

Tags: entity-framework-core

So all the tutorials cover the initial scaffolding to generate views.  What's the ongoing process for adding more tables and generating more models?

So here is the setup..  I have setup EFC, I added a few tables, I ran the scaffold command to create my models.   Now I have added a few more tables.  What is the workflow for creating additional models?   Or at this point just create them manually?

Comment: Run the scaffold for creating the models again...

Comment: ...and look forward to feature [#831](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/831). 